# How to display " as in inches in my program

Tags: java

Thanks for trying to help me.

The program that I am working on is supposed to ask a person for their input in feet and inches

`2' 2 2/2"` <--- (This format)

However, I cannot come up with a way that enables such kind of user input.

The program is composed of three classes

- Fraction
- Pair
- Mix

**Java:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Mix extends Fraction {

  public Mix ( int n, int m) {
    super (n,m);
  }

  public String displayMix() {
  String str="";
    if (first < second) 
    str=first+ "'" + first%second +"/"+second+"\"";
    else 
    str=first+"'" +(first+second)+"/"+second+"\"";

    return str; 
  } //display

  public static String get () {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a mixed-format number:");
    String userInput = scan.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.trim();
    System.out.println("Input is: "+ userInput);
    return (userInput);
  } //get


  public static void main(String [] args) {
    String userInput;
    int[]iA = {0,0,0,1};

    userInput = Mix.get();
    iA=parse(userInput);
    Mix f = new Mix ( iA[0] , (iA[1]*iA[2])+(iA[3]) );
    System.out.println("Number = " + f.displayMix());

    userInput = Mix.get();
    iA=parse(userInput);
    Mix g = new Mix ( iA[0] , iA[1] * iA[3] + iA[2]);
    System.out.println("Number = " + g.displayMix());

    Mix h = Mix.add (f,g);
    System.out.println("Sum ="+ h.displayMix());
  } // main


  public static Mix add (Mix f, Mix g) {
    int gtop=       f.first+g.first;

    int gbottom=    f.second+g.second;
    return(new Mix ( gtop, gbottom));
  } //add


  public static int[] parse (String userInput) {
    int [] sA = {0,0,0,1};
    int pos = userInput.indexOf("'");

    String sNum0 = userInput.substring(0,pos);
    pos = userInput.indexOf("'");
    sA[0]= Integer.parseInt(sNum0);

    String sNum = userInput.substring(0,pos);
    pos = sNum.indexOf("  ");
    sA[1]= Integer.parseInt(sNum);

    String sNum2 = userInput.substring(pos + 1);
    pos = sNum2.indexOf("/");

    String sTop= sNum2.substring (pos +3);
    pos = sNum2.indexOf("\"");
    sA[2] = Integer.parseInt(sTop);

    String sBot = sNum2.substring(pos +1);

    sA[3] = Integer.parseInt(sBot);

    // 2' 2 2/2
    return (sA);
  }
} //parse
```

I have managed to get result after inputting

```
2' 2 2/2"1
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but something is off since I need a number after the " to get a result back.

I am pretty sure that something is wrong with the parsing method, I just dont know where it is.

**This is the Fraction class**

```
public class Fraction extends Pair {
  //attributes: NONE

  public Fraction(int n, int m) {
    super(n,m);
    int g=gcd(n,m);
    first = first;
    second=second/g;
  } //Fraction


  public void display2() {
    System.out.print(first);
    System.out.print("/");
    System.out.println(second);
  } //display


  public Fraction add (Fraction f1, Fraction f2) {
    int gtop=f1.first * f2.second
    + f2.first * f1.second;
    int gbottom= f1.second * f2.second;
    return (new Fraction(gtop,gbottom));
  }


  public static int gcd (int n, int m) {
    while ( n!=m) {
      if (n>m) n=n-m;
      else m=m-n;
    } //while
    return (n);
  } //gcd
} //class
```

**This is the Pair class**

```
public class Pair {
  int first;
  int second;

  public Pair(int n, int m) {
    first=n;
    second=m;
  } //Pair


  public void display() {
    //pseudo_code is here
    System.out.print("First integer="+first);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Second integer="+second);
  } //display


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //pseudo-code is here
    Pair f= new Pair(2,4);
    f.display();
  } //main
} //class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am pretty sure that something is wrong with the parsing method, i just dont know where it is.

Absolutely.

For debugging purposes it is always best to use distinct values in situations where you are parsing. For your input string `2' 2 2/2"` you could potentially receive false positives if you attempt to print the output. Providing a new input string `"1' 2 3/4"5"` to your `parse` method yields an array `int[] sA` of `1 1 5 5`. Now to find the issue.

```
int pos = userInput.indexOf("'");

String sNum0 = userInput.substring(0, pos);
pos = userInput.indexOf("'"); //why getting a position you already have?
sA[0] = Integer.parseInt(sNum0);
```

The snippet works for retrieving the first number. The one oddity is evident in the comment I provided. Next the issues begin,

```
 String sNum = userInput.substring(0, pos);
 pos = sNum.indexOf("  ");
 sA[1] = Integer.parseInt(sNum);
```

You get the same `2` out of the input again, and then attempt to look for double whitespaces in a 1 char length string. Your `pos` becomes `-1` and you duplicate your data assignment `sA[0]` and `sA[1]` have the same value.

```
String sNum2 = userInput.substring(pos + 1);
pos = sNum2.indexOf("/");
```

Next, since your `pos` is now `-1` you substring then entire userInput resulting in `sNum2` and userInput essentially `.equals()` each other. `pos` is now equal 6.

```
String sTop = sNum2.substring(pos + 3);
pos = sNum2.indexOf("\"");
sA[2] = Integer.parseInt(sTop);
```

`pos + 3` is why you have to enter the extra input character.

I won't go into much detail about how and where to fix the problems, as there are several solutions. However, if you are allowed to use the `.split()` method, I would strongly suggest you take advantage of it.

```
 String[] tokens = "1' 2 3/4\"".split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as per the title...

A literal double quote must be escaped:

```
String length = "6\"";
System.out.println(length); // 6"
```

For more information on escaping characters, see [JLS - 3.10.6: Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

Comment: I see that my title is misleading. Thanks for the answer, however, it is not what i intended to ask. The program accepts the ' which represents feet, however i cannot get it to accept the " for inches.